# Python module import

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

I have a set of python modules I just installed, the sys.path is this:

```
'/root/work/FirstPeak3', '/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic-0.2.4.dev0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nupic-0.2.4.dev0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/root/Applications/numenta_src', '/root/Applications/numenta_src/nupic', '/root/Applications/numenta_src/nupic/data'
```

but when I tried to reference a module in my run.py, I get this:

```
File "./run.py", line 37, in <module>
    import nupic.data.inference_shifter
ImportError: No module named data.inference_shifter
```

This problem goes away if I copy the inference_shifter.py from one of the paths above, e.g. `'/root/Applications/numenta_src/nupic/data'`. Can someone tell me why?  Thanks. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you make `data/` a package?

Comment: yes, it has the __init__.py in it.

Comment: nupic should be a module too, i.e., both `/root/Applications/numenta_src/nupic` and `/root/Applications/numenta_src/nupic/data` should have `__init__.py` files.  Also, these paths should not be in `sys.path`. If this doesn't help, try posting a small, complete script that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
import importlib
import sys
import csv
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
#sys.path.insert(0, "/root/Applications/numenta_src")
sys.path.insert(0, "/root/Applications/numenta_src/nupic")
sys.path.append("/root/Applications/numenta_src/nupic/data")
print (sys.path)

Comment: #import inference_shifter
#import nupic.data.inference_shifter
from nupic.data.inference_shifter import InferenceShifter
#from root.Applications.numenta_src.nupic.data.inference_shifter import InferenceShifter
from nupic.frameworks.opf.metrics import MetricSpec
from nupic.frameworks.opf.modelfactory import ModelFactory
from nupic.frameworks.opf.predictionmetricsmanager import MetricsManager

import nupic_output

global myTimeStamp
global myConsumption

Comment: sorry i had to break up the script into two parts.

Comment: Any answer on this question? I have the same problem.